# Protractor querying SQL Server database (MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to execute a simple query on SQL Server but when I run it with protractor it just runs quickly and doesnt return (log) anything. I would appreciate any hints, working examples or pointers to what I am doing wrong and how to exec a SQL query on SQL Server with protractor.

```
var sql = require('mssql');

describe('test db connection', function () {

  it('tests db connection', function () {

    ConnectDB()

  })

  function ConnectDB() {

    var config = {
      user: 'user',
      password: 'password',
      server: 'xyz.database.windows.net',
      database: 'dbdev',

      options: {
        encrypt: true
      }
    }

    var connection = new sql.Connection(config)
    connection.connect(function (err) {
      console.log(err)
    })

    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query('select * from Config where [Key] like \'HidePreop%\'', function (err, recordeset) {
      var res = recordeset;
      console.log(res)
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protractor test - `it` blocks will only wait for webDriverJS commands in Protractor control flow to finish and any other async activity you have to manually make the `it` block wait using `done`.

In this case -

```
describe('test db connection', function () {    
    it('tests db connection', function (done) {
        // Any method that returns a promise. Similary if your method returns a callback you can handle accordingly
        ConnectDB().then(function _onSuccess(){
            done();
        }).catch(function _onFailure(err){
            done.fail(err);
        })
    })
});
```

And I would modify your funcion - `ConnectDB()` to return a promise based on the resolution of the callback provide by the [mssql npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql). [Refer here](https://www.promisejs.org/) on how to convert a callback to Promises. its an awesome tutorial.

```
function ConnectDB() {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
        var config = {
            user: 'user',
            .............
        };
        var connection = new sql.Connection(config);
        connection.connect(function (err) {
            reject(err);
        });

        var request = new sql.Request(connection);
        request.query('select * from Config where [Key] like \'HidePreop%\'', function (err, recordeset) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else fulfill(recordeset);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: i try to use your way it says that this function has been depreceated

Answer (score 1):

I access the MSSQL database using this configuration in it's own file and then import it into the test file so I can use it a bit like a fake page object.
I would highly recommend storing any database information in an external file outside of the repository. I am using a .env file from the npm library dotenv which can be installed using `npm install --save-dev dotenv`

```
//db.js
const sql = require('mssql');

require('dotenv').config();

var config = {
  user: process.env.MSSQL_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.MSSQL_PASSWORD,
  server: process.env.MSSQL_SERVER,
  database: 'YOURDB',
  options: {
   encrypt: true
  }
};

module.exports = {

/** Define sql queries here  */
  deleteEmployeeByLastName(lastName) {
    let my_query = `DELETE FROM dbo.Employee WHERE LastName='${lastName}'`;
    sql.connect(config).then(function () {
      new sql.Request()
        .query(my_query).then(function (recordset) {}).catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

The test file should look something like this

```
//test.js
var db = require('db.js');

describe('Employee Management', function () {    

    it('Deleting an employee', function (done) {
       db.deleteEmployeeByLastName('Pmurt');
       //REST OF CODE HERE
       //...
       //...
       done();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me and then I found this link - https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/access-sql-server-in-nodejs
I applied what they suggested 
Also, I took the information from the link, placed this in a function, placed the function into a class...

```
export class SqlDo {
  static serverDo() {
```

//the info from the link

and added more after the

```
var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
```

section.
I added

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.get('http://localhost:5000');
```

and this adds the output to a screenshot which is collected by the screenshot reporter.
Then I created a spec and in the 'it' I call the class.function

```
import { SqlDo } from './server';

describe('', () => {
  it('test connection and output', () => {
    SqlDo.serverDo();
  });
});
```

All worked with the database output rendered and in a screenshot and the screenshot captured in the html report.

I hope this helps anyone still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

**Posting a working example for mssql@4.0.4**

```
var sql = require('mssql');

describe('test db connection', function () {
it('tests db connection', function (done) {
    ConnectDB().then(function _onSuccess(_returned){
        console.log(_returned.recordset[0].FirstPSPOrderId)

        done();
    }).catch(function _onFailure(err){
        done.fail(err);
    })
})
```

});

```
function ConnectDB() {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    var config = {
        user: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        server: 'xxx',
        port: 'xxx',
        database: 'xxxxxx',

        options: {
            encrypt: true
        }
};
    var connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) reject(err);

    //});

    let query = "select [FirstPSPOrderId] from XYZ"
    connection.request()
    .query(query, (err, recordeset) => {

        console.dir('Record set: ' + recordeset)
        console.dir('Err: ' + err)

        if (err) reject(err);
        else fulfill(recordeset);
    });
});

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

an updated answer based on async/await:

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/mssql": "4.0.11",
    "msnodesqlv8": "0.6.11",
    "mssql": "4.3.0",
}
```

test:

```
import { ConnectionPool } from 'mssql/msnodesqlv8';

describe('any test', () => {

    it('should prepare db', async () => {
        const connectionString = 'Server=#server#;Database=#db#;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver=msnodesqlv8'

        const connectionPool: ConnectionPool = new ConnectionPool(connectionString);

        await connectionPool.connect();

        const result = await connectionPool.request().query('select 'Hello World' as resultColumn');

        connectionPool.close();

        expect(result.recordset[0].resultColumn).toEqual('Hello World');
    }

}
```

Substitute query with a sql statement that prepares data. e.g. Delete From Users Where...
Then use result.affectedRows to see if delete worked